# what is Work interface in package commonj.work?

Tags: java

In my project I came accross some classes implementing work interface.The working seems similar to as threads.I searched the internet and found this

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57014_01/wls/WLAPI/commonj/work/class-use/Work.html

it wasn't much helpful.I wish to know the basic idea of Work and how it is different from Threads in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have found definition written in doc i.e ***"Dispatches a Work asynchronously***" it means , you can distribute work to another thread. 
Let's understand by example : Suppose you went to a bakery shop and ordered a cake [black forest] , now you remembered you have to purchase some house-hold items . So , you have already ordered the cake and went to bring house-hold items. Till the time cake is being prepared you are focusing on another work .

Same goes with this work interface also.

Comment: CommonJ is a  3rd party framework and Thread is a built-in feature of Java.